# Landscape-mode page curl issue in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, animation, landscape, page-curl

In my app, I have a page curl effect. The page curl effect works correctly in portrait mode whereas in landscape mode the page curl ending takes place at the corner of the i pad.

In landscape mode I want the page to be get separated in the middle as in the following figure.[image]

But my page curl effects looks as the following figure.[image]

I am using the following code:

```
-(void)PresentView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0  animations:^
    {
                         CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];

                         [animation setDelegate:self];
                         [animation setDuration:0.7];

                         [animation setTimingFunction:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];

                         animation.type = @"pageCurl";

                         animation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
                         animation.endProgress = 0.65;

                         [animation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
                         [m_container.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"pageCurlAnimation"];  

                         [m_container addSubview:self];
                         ;}  

     ];    
}
```

How do I get the page curl animation in landscape mode as in the first figure?

Comment: it may help to u https://github.com/lomanf/PaperStack also see this link http://api.mutado.com/mobile/paperstack/

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust two properties of `UIPageViewController`:

- Set `doubleSided` to `YES`, so that each page has content on both of its sides
- Set `spineLocation` to `UIPageViewControllerSpineLocationMid` so that you have two pages joined in the middle of view